# how can i select mysql row where field contains exact integrer into string?

Tags: php, mysql

i have field in mysql row what contains:  5,15,25,30

i need return true for integrer 30, and return false for 3.

what mysql string function is?

when i using LIKE %3% return is true, but mysql field no contain integrer 3 (string yes but integrer no)

thankyou vary much Jozef

Answer (score 2):

Use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(30, field) > 0
```

As a note:  storing lists of ids in comma-delimited strings is a bad idea.  You should be using a junction table instead.